# Dynamic match and copy/paste in new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I need to extract data from multiple workbooks:
First in each workbook I have 3 columns (in my example: Alpha, Bravo, Charlie) with the same headers but not always in the same order.. under them the data I want to copy except the empty cells.
Each column need to be pasted after each other in the first row in a new workbook with additional cells (fixed text) in-between.
To add complexity Alpha need to be pasted twice with additional prefix, and data in Charlie only need the first 14 characters in every cell.
To end this the new workbook will be saved in txt, with double space as separator "  "

Right now I lack knowledge in VBA so I've errors, and it's messy, I don't know how I can copy the first 14 characters and it doesnt work at all.
I wrote the macro on mobile, it lack tabulation...

```
   sub transfert()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Workbooks.Add
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
Filename:="C:\users\user\desktop\transfert.txt"
FileFormat:=xlText

dim wb_a as workbook
dim wb_b as workbook
dim ws_a as worksheet
dim wd_b as worksheet
Dim cl1 as long
Dim cl2 as long
Dim cl3  as long
Dim lr1 as long
Dim lr2 as long
Dim lr3 as long
dim d1 as long

Set wb_a = Workbooks("original.xlsm")
Set wb_b = Workbooks("transfert.txt")
Set ws_a = wb_a.Worksheets("from")
Set ws_b = wb_b.Worksheets("Sheet1")

[A1].Value = "FirstText"

with ws_a
if not IsError (application.match("Alpha", .Rows(1), 0)) Then
cl1 = Application.Match("Alpha", .Rows(1), 0)
lr1 = ws_a.cells(Rows.count, "cl1").End(xlUp).Row
.Range(cells(2, "cl1"), Cells("lr1", "cl1")).Copy
Else
MsgBow "Error Alpha"
end if
end with

ws_b.range("b1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xpastevalues, skipblank:=True, Transpose:=True

With Selection
For Each d1 In Selection
r.Value = 123
Next
End with

ws_b.cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).PasteSpecial paste:=xpastevalues, skipblank:=true, transpose:=True
ws_b.cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Value = "SecondText"

with ws_a
if not IsError (application.match("Bravo", .Rows(1), 0)) Then
cl2 = Application.Match("Bravo", .Rows(1), 0)
lr2 = ws_a.cells(Rows.count, "cl2").End(xlUp).Row
.Range(cells(2, "cl2"), Cells("lr2", "cl2")).Copy
Else
MsgBow "Error Bravo"
end if
end with

ws_b.cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).PasteSpecial paste:=xpastevalues, skipblank:=true, transpose:=True
ws_b.cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Value = "ThirdText"

with ws_a
if not IsError (application.match("Charlie", .Rows(1), 0)) Then
cl3 = Application.Match("Charlie", .Rows(1), 0)
lr3 = ws_a.cells(Rows.count, "cl3").End(xlUp).Row
.Range(cells(2, "cl3"), Cells("lr3", "cl3")).Copy
Else
MsgBow "Error Charlie"
end if
end with

ws_b.cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).PasteSpecial paste:=xpastevalues, skipblank:=true, transpose:=True
ws_b.cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Value = "FourthText"

with ws_b.application
.decimalSeparator = "  "
.ThousandsSeparator = "  "
.UseSystemSeparator = False
End with

wb_b.Close SaveChange:=True
MsgBox "Done"

Application.cutcopymode = false
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Would you please [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58648972/edit) to clearly and cleanly state **A)** the single specific question you are asking, **B)** description of your current state of the data, and **C)** description of the output of data.  Any screenshots or mock-data would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe you're looking for `variant arrays` to help you with the data, where you find the headers you want and manipulate them as part of a second array which is then appended to your destination sheet.  Specific to the "first 14 characters in Charlie" `left(string,14)` would do that.

Comment: An additional point, you can save yourself some memory allocation such that: 
`Set ws_a = Workbooks("original.xlsm").Worksheets("from")`